# Change Second Date Input Based on First Date Input and Vice Versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to link two datepickers so that when i chose a date in first datepicker then the second datepicker should change too.

Right now I am using this date-picker: http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/

For now, I pick dates manually in these two datepickers:

```html
<input type="text" value='' required id='shamsi' class='uk-input solarDate'>
<input type="text" value='' required id='gregorian' class='uk-input gregorianDate'>
```

With the help of below JavaScript code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".solarDate").pDatepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    autoClose: true,
                    dayPicker: {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "titleFormat": "YYYY MMMM"
                    },
                    monthPicker: {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "titleFormat": "YYYY"
                    },
                    yearPicker:{
                        enabled: 'true'
                    }
                });

                $(".gregorianDate").pDatepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    autoClose: true,
                    calendarType: 'gregorian',
                    dayPicker: {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "titleFormat": "YYYY MMMM"
                    },
                    monthPicker: {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "titleFormat": "YYYY"
                    },
                    yearPicker:{
                        enabled: 'true'
                    }
                });
            });
```

Now, I want to link these two datepickers. For instance, if i pick a Jalali/Shamsi date in `solarDate` datepicker then it should automatically convert to Gregorian date in `gregorianDate` datepicker and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onSelect function:

```
$(".solarDate").pDatepicker({
    onSelect: function(unix){
        // Change your gregorianDate value here

        console.log('datepicker select : ' + unix);
    },
...
})
```

More: http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/example/#onselect

Comment: Tried but not working. I think it only work in linux servers, but i am not sure.